# in JTable, How can I disable to edit a specified colunm or row?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have some trouble and I looking for some solution.

But by now, I can't do.

I ask some guys an issue about JTable.

This code makes me disable to edit all cells.

```
final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
              return true;
        }
};
```

But, I want some code for me not to edit a specified colunm or row.

So, If you help me, I will appreciate it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## if - else will help you out :

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
   if(yourConditionMet)   <--- you can apply your check
       return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```